# 2 instances of ManyToMany for same entity in same class

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I want to add  2 instances of same object with manyToMany relation.

```
class A {

     /**

 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="RelatedEntity", inversedBy="teachers", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="table1",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="class_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="related_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $myFirstEntities;


     /**

 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="RelatedEntity", inversedBy="students", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="table2",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="class_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="related_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $mySecondEntities;
}



class RelatedEntity
{
  /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="myFirstEntities", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $teachers;

  /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="mySecondEntities", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $students;

}
```

When I use the

```
        php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyApp
```

the program generate **a unique method to add** entity named:

```
public function addRelatedEntity(\MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\RelatedEntity $myFirstEntities)
{
    $this->myFirstEntities[] = $myFirstEntities;
}
```

So I can"t add mySecondEntities. How can I do. I have the possibility to add it in manual method but automatic method it is not possible?

My question is can I use 2 manytomany relation of a specific class into  the same class? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

doctrine:generate:entities supposed to be used one time when you need generate entities, it does not guarantee that generated mapping will be 100% correct, http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#entity-generation:

> This command is not suited for constant usage. It is a little helper
>   and does not support all the mapping edge cases very well. You still
>   have to put work in your entities after using this command.

You can have mapping many-to-many for the same class, just do it manually

```
public function addFirstEntity(\MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\RelatedEntity $myFirstEntities)
{
    $this->myFirstEntities[] = $myFirstEntities;
} 

public function addSecondEntity(\MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\RelatedEntity $mySecondEntities)
{
    $this->mySecondEntities[] = $mySecondEntities;
}
```